# IT Hit Ajax File Browser - Open OS's File Manager - login prompt

Tags: authentication, ithit-ajax-file-browser

I noticed that 'Open OS's File Manager' feature prompts for user login on first access.

Is it possible to configure Ajax File Browser to use 'Open OS's File Manager' feature without login prompt?

I already set user credentials on Ajax File Browser page (ajaxFileBrowser.GetSession().SetCredentials) but I see that it doesn't pass these credentials to the 'Open OS's File Manager' feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general there is no way to avoid the credentials dialog. The reason is the credentials that you specify in a web browser are stored in a web browser, when the OS file manager is run there is no way to share the credentials with that application.

The possible solution would be implementing Url-authentiation and pass authentication token in the URL: http://server/[SessionID1234567890]/path/file.docx